# On an NVIDIA GPU with multiple graphics cards (K80 for example), why does torch.cuda.device_count() return 1?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I ran the following code on a Tesla K80, which as I understand consists of 2 GK210 graphics cards, each with 12GB of on chip ram, connected by something called a PLX switch. I am confused how at the pytorch level, the fact that there are two graphics cards is hidden from the user

```
import torch
torch.cuda.device_count() # 1
```

(my hunch is that tensorflow provides this same abstraction)

Follow up questions:

1. If I am training a model with pytorch, and I run `nvidia-smi` and see that the GPU is fully utilized, I would assume this means that both  GK210's are at 100% utilization. How does pytorch distribute kernels across the two GK210's, and can I have faith that this is being done efficiently? (I.e. being done in a way that minimized data transfer between the two cards). Any resources that explain how this works would be much appreciated.
2. If I were writing a CUDA application, could I pin a CUDA stream to each card, and explicitly manage data transfers between the two cards?

Comment: There is no abstraction of the sort you speculate and if you are only seeing 1 device, something in your OS setup or hardware is broken or you are using a cloud service or some kind of virtualization which only exposes 1 GPU. You should see 2 devices. How tensorflow or PyTorch handles two devices is an implementation detail of those frameworks. Nothing automagic happens

Comment: This code was run on an AWS p2.xlarge instance, which according to AWS, everything I have read on the internet, and `nvidia-smi` contains a single K80 GPU, which should contain 2 GK210s. So maybe this is related to something funky in the way that AWS sets up GPU instances.

Comment: A "single K80" means "half a K80 card" or one GPU, not two

Comment: correct, the p2.xlarge instance actually has half of a single K80 card, only a single GPU device.  This is expected behavior.  Pytorch isn't hiding GPUs from the user, and neither is nvidia-smi.  If you had a complete K80, nvidia-smi would show 2 GPU devices.